# Sending a file in post method on form submit and populating a datatable with the json response

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I have a datatable defined this way which i can not change .

```
var table = $('#dt-table').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "processing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    'bPaginate' : true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "sAjaxSource": 'myurl',
    some other fields})
```

On click of a button i want to make a post request and pass a file to the backend. After searching i found out that i can change the table settings using

`var oSettings = table.fnSettings();`

So my click button action is something like :

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    console.log(data);
    var oSettings = table.fnSettings();
    oSettings.sAjaxSource="/home/file_upload/;
    oSettings.sServerMethod="POST";
    //oSettings.aoData.push(data)
    table.fnDraw();
```

So what i am not able to do is how do i pass this formdata to my backend . I  am able to get the post method in the backed but not the file . 
The basic motto is to populate the data table with json data obtained from the server by processing this file . Also i am using django form which looks like this :

```
 <form  name="form" method="post" id="file-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='upload-btn'>Upload</button>
</form>
```

If you need any extra info , please comment . Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I do understand this was a very long and non-specific question, but i will try to answer it. This question and answer is specific to django.

The django form mentioned in question needed one minor modification of adding an action field which basically means which url you want to hit when this form is submitted.
So the new form looks something like this :

```
<form  name="form" method="post" id="file-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank"  action="your_url">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <b>Select a csv file :<input type="file"  id="file" name="file" /></b>
   <!--<label for="file" class="btn btn-file">Select a csv file</label>-->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='upload-btn'>Load</button>
</form>
```

To capture this url on the server side, you should include one line in your urls.py file which will call views function when this url is hit .

```
url(r'^your_url/$', 'process_file',name='process_file')
```

Please not that this `{your_url}` is relative to your current path in the browser as it is not starting with a `/`. So have your url as per your form. More info on django urls [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Now you should define a function in your views.py file with the name process_file {as per the current url}. Django will take care of passing the file for you.

```
def process_file(request, template_name='response.html'):
if(request.method=='POST'):
    form = FileUploader(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        filename=request.FILES['file'].name
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            f = request.FILES['file']
            json_data= handle_uploaded_file(f,can_edit)
            return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), RequestContext(request))
        else :
            logging.error("File with other than csv extension")
            return HttpResponse("Please choose a csv file only")
    else :
        logging.error("Not a valid form")
        return HttpResponse("Please Choose a file then click the upload button")
else :
    logging.error("Method is not post")
    return HttpResponse("Something Went wrong , Please try again")
```

You can access the file in your views file using these lines as shown in the code above:

`form = FileUploader(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        filename=request.FILES['file'].name`

Then process the file  as per your requirements.

Now the data you have sent from your backend will be accessible in your front end inside the template. So i had to create another html file which has a datatable which does not have serverside processing set to be true. We are supplying the data to the datatable using this line `"aaData":dataset.aaData`. 
    
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    var dataset=JSON.parse( '{{json_data | escapejs }}');
    var table = $('#dt-table').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "processing": true,
    "aaData":dataset.aaData,
    "bPaginate" : true,
     some other fields})
```

If you came  to this point reading this answer, the crux is we now have our data in our template. We add some js code in our template to provide this data to our datatable. This way i was able to pass a file to backend, process that file and then display the response in my front end.